# Electron fs - EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts'

Tags: windows, electron, file-permissions, fs, hosts

Is there a way in electron or nodejs to ask the user to give permission to edit the file, e.g. like the popup if you want to install a program and you need the admin permissions to do so.

I don't have any problems reading the file with default permission settings. If I change the file permissions in the Windows explorer my electron app can write/edit the file, but that not solves my problem.

```
const fs = require("fs");
let letPathtoFile = "C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts";

function funcReadFile() {

    fs.readFile(letPathtoFile, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
      }

        $('#idReadFileContent').text(data);
    });
}


function funcWriteFile() {
    let letNewContent = $('#idWriteFileContent').val();
    fs.writeFile(letPathtoFile, letNewContent, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        alert(err.message);
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    alert("File saved");
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way - you can use either `sudo-prompt` ([NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sudo-prompt), [GitHub](https://github.com/jorangreef/sudo-prompt)) or `electron-sudo` ([NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-sudo), [GitHub](https://github.com/automation-stack/electron-sudo)).

You'll need to do an `exec` command & a graphical OS prompt should show up.